# Entity Framework - Navigate in multiple DbSets

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Let's say that I have these models:

```
public class TextDocument
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public virtual List<Paragraph> Paragraphs { get; set; }
}

public class Paragraph
{
   public virtual TextDocument Document { get; set; } 
   public int Order { get; set; }
   public string Text { get; set; }
}

public class Image
{
    public virtual Paragraph Paragraph {get; set; }
    public virtual TextDocument Document { get; set; } 
    public string Url { get; set }
}
```

And now, I need to navigate in `TextDocuments`, `Paragraphs`, `Images`, `Paragraphs` in `TextDocuments`, `Images` in `Paragraphs`, `Images` in `TextDocuments`, etc.

How do I "connect" the models?
What I'm asking is:

1. How to make the DataContext? Only for the TextDocument?
2. With this, how do I get, for example, all Images without knowing the Id's, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is not clear.
Also your model is a bit strange. `TextDocument` does not include a list of `Image`s. But `Image` both includes back navigations to `Paragraph` and `TextDocument`. I think you need to add `Image` list to `Paragraph` and remove `TextDocument` from `Image`. This way you will enable `Document`s to have `Pharagraph`s and `Pharagraph`s to have `Image`s;

```
public class TextDocument
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public virtual List<Paragraph> Paragraphs { get; set; }
}
public class Paragraph
{
   public virtual TextDocument Document { get; set; } 
   public int Order { get; set; }
   public string Text { get; set; }
   public virtual List<Image> Images { get; set; }
}
public class Image
{
    public virtual Paragraph Paragraph {get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set }
}
```

To create a context create a class deriving from DbContext, and add your entity sets;

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Image> Images { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TextDocument> TextDocuments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Paragraph> Paragraphs { get; set; }
}
```

to fetch the images of a specific text document with id equals to 3;

```
using(MyContext context = new MyContext())
{
    var temp = context.TextDocuments.Include("Paragraph.Image").Where(q => q.Id == 3);
    var imageList = temp.Paragraphs.Select(q => q.Images).ToList();
}
```

to select all images;

```
using(MyContext context = new MyContext())
{
    var allImages = context.Images.ToList();
}
```

Refer to [this blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx) post which has a good tutorial about EF Code First.

Comment: Thank you, it solves my problem! I didn't know about the LINQ Include command, but now it makes sense!

Comment: Thank you, that's what I wanted to get.

Answer (score 0):

You are in the right direction, looks like you have connected the models. I assume that you can navigate through the properties without any problems with this class definitions.

One thing that is missing is the Primary Key definitions (Id)  for Paragraph and Image classes.

Edit 1:

You can only add a

```
public DbSet<TextDocument> {get;set;}
```

in your DbContext, and thus you will be able to navigate down to images. Likewise you can only place DbSet for Image in a DbContext and you should be able to navigate up to TextDocument.
What you are trying to achieve is not clear.
Edit 2:

```
public class Paragraph
{
   public int Id {get; set;} // add this
   public virtual List<Images> Images {get; set;} // and add this
   public virtual TextDocument Document { get; set; } 
   public int Order { get; set; }
   public string Text { get; set; }

}
```